# MySQL can only use 61 tables in a join

Tags: mysql, join, relational-division

Below are some simplified table structures

employee

```
+----+----------+
| id | name     |
+----+----------+
|  1 | "Andrew" |
|  2 | "April"  |
|  3 | "John"   |
+----+----------+
```

tag

```
+----+---------+
| id | name    |
+----+---------+
|  1 | "Tag 1" |
|  2 | "Tag 2" |
|  3 | "Tag 3" |
|  4 | "Tag 4" |
+----+---------+
```

employee_tag

```
+------------------+--------+
| id | employee_id | tag_id |
+------------------+--------+
|  1 |           1 |      1 |
|  2 |           1 |      2 |
|  3 |           1 |      3 |
|  4 |           1 |      4 |
|  5 |           2 |      1 |
|  6 |           2 |      4 |
|  7 |           3 |      4 |
+------------------+--------+
```

A simple data structure in where you can see that:

- Andrew has the tags : Tag 1, Tag 2, Tag 3 and Tag 4
- April has the tags: Tag 1 and Tag 4
- John has the tags: Tag 4

I want to have a list of all employees having all the tags I specify by name.
So, suppose I want to have the employees which are tagged with "Tag 1" and "Tag 4" I wrote this query.

```
SELECT employee.id, employee.name FROM employee

INNER JOIN employee_tag employee_tag_alias_1 ON employee_tag_alias_1.employee_id = employee.id
INNER JOIN tag tag_alias_1 ON employee_tag_alias_1.tag_id = tag_alias_1.id

INNER JOIN employee_tag employee_tag_alias_2 ON employee_tag_alias_2.employee_id = employee.id
INNER JOIN tag tag_alias_2 ON employee_tag_alias_2.tag_id = tag_alias_2.id

WHERE tag_alias_1.name = "Tag 1" AND tag_alias_2.name = "Tag 4"
```

As you can see I have multiple inner joins for each tag I'm searching for using aliases.

The results in this case are as expected.
It returns Andrew and April since they are the ones having these tags.

Specifying another tag to search for, I create two other joins with a unique alias like this

```
INNER JOIN employee_tag employee_tag_alias_3 ON employee_tag_alias_3.employee_id = employee.id
INNER JOIN tag tag_alias_3 ON employee_tag_alias_3.tag_id = tag_alias_3.id
```

The tables in this example are small, but in reality I have dozens of tags.
So if I would search for 100 different tags I have to create 200 different joins and then MySQL throws the error : Too many tables; MySQL can only use 61 tables in a join.

I was using the IN operator first like this :

```
SELECT employee.id, employee.name FROM employee

INNER JOIN employee_tag ON employee_tag.employee_id = employee.id
INNER JOIN tag ON employee_tag.tag_id = tag.id

WHERE tag.name IN ("Tag 1", "Tag 4")

GROUP BY employee.id
```

In this case the result was unwanted (though expected), because John is in the list as well.

So the question is: how can I accomplish to get only those employees having all the tags (even 100) specified.

The database engine is MySql and I generate the statement through PHP.
Suggesting that I should use any other database or structure is not an option because I'm not the one to decide this.

Comment: only 61 i find it more than sufficient, try your last approach but with 1  where and 1 EXISTS

Comment: Your task is a type of [tag:relational-division] query. Follow that tag here on Stack Overflow to see other solutions. Some solutions don't need to use joins, so they are more suitable when you want to match many values.

Comment: @nbk Thanks for the suggestion, without further explanation however this means not much to me. Could you elaborate a bit more please?

Comment: please test one of the duplicates, if that doesn't work, edit your question and i will look what is wrong with it, bills suggestions is very godd then it woill give you many approaches besides mine `WHERE tag.name =  (Tag 1" AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM ... WHERe tag.name "Tag 4" and employee.id = e.id)` so in the line of that

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: A [mre] includes: cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) PS Please avoid social & meta commentary in posts. Eg don't say that a sentence is a question, just ask the question. Clarity comes from good organization & phrasing, not adding emphasis.

Comment: I was able to produce a satisfying outcome.
Using the NOT EXISTS and IN operators.

I want to share it with anybody interested : https://dbfiddle.uk/a-lWbjbI

Maybe not so efficient (in a system with 100s of tags) , because the code which can be seen in the fiddle, fetches all the tags an employee doesn't have first in order to use that to negate it...

Thanks @BillKarwin pointing to [relational-division]